# How to send a pdf via e-mail from Java

Tags: java, email, email-attachments

How do I submit a pdf file to a generic e-mail from Java application?

Comment: Please edit your question to remove all mention of PDFBox. Your question is basically how to send a file through smtp with java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Send E-Mail with PDF file as Attachment using reference of this -

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;  

class SendMailWithAttachment
{ 
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {    
        String to="XYZ@abc.com"; //Email address of the recipient
        final String user="ABC@XYZ.com"; //Email address of sender
        final String password="xxxxx";  //Password of the sender's email

        //Get the session object      
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();  

        //Here pass your smtp server url
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "mail.javatpoint.com");   
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");    

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,   
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {   
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);    }   });       

        //Compose message      
        try{    
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);    
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));     
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));    
            message.setSubject("Message Aleart");         

            //Create MimeBodyPart object and set your message text        
            BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();     
            messageBodyPart1.setText("This is message body");          

            //Create new MimeBodyPart object and set DataHandler object to this object        
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();      
            String filename = "YourPDFFileName.pdf";//change accordingly     
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);    
            messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));    
            messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);             

            //Create Multipart object and add MimeBodyPart objects to this object        
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();    
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);     
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);      

            //Set the multiplart object to the message object    
            message.setContent(multipart );        

            //Send message    
            Transport.send(message);      
            System.out.println("message sent....");   

        }catch (MessagingException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}  
    }
}
```

You can also refer to [JavaTPoint](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-attachment-with-email-using-java-mail-api)

Comment: Thank's. But I receive this error:

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1829)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1368)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:886)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:191)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
 at testemail.SendMailWithAttachment.main(SendMailWithAttachment.java:53)

Comment: @Daniel-san I think you simply copied the code above. I have added comments in my answer please check that.

Answer (score -2):

delete the part :
//Here pass your smtp server url
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host",
"mail.javatpoint.com");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

```
And paste the code below : 

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");  //587
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
```